# TreeView SelectedItemChanged not firing Command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Despite scouring previously asked questions of the same nature, and finding quite a few, I'm still stumped as to why this isn't working for me.

I have a TreeView -

```
<Window ... xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <TreeView Name="Folders" ItemsSource="{Binding Directories}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FolderChangedCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

I am trying to bind the SelectedItemChanged event to a command in my ViewModel -

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;

internal class MainVM : VMBase
{
    private DelegateCommand FolderChangedCommand { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        FolderChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand(FolderChanged);
    }

    private void FolderChanged()
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Yet my command is never fired. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might it have to do with the FolderChangedCommand being private? I suspect it's supposed to be public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The databinding engine needs `public` properties as a [binding source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#classes):

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must
>   be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface
>   properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected,
>   private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base
>   implementation

But your command is `private` so change it to:

```
public DelegateCommand FolderChangedCommand { get; set; }
```

And also make sure that your `MainVM` is correctly set as the `DataContext` of your window. 
You can find more info about debugging databindings in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).